# Swift: Using Logger with optionals

Tags: swift, logging, macos-big-sur

I have watched through the WWDC 2020 and thought I would switch my code to use the new Logger syntax.

I often want to print the value of optional variables which I can do with the simple print command. If I try this with the new Logger commands I get a "Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'NSObject'" error. What is the recommended way of doing this with Logger?

```
import os

let logger = Logger(subsystem: "com.example.Fruta", category: "giftcards")

let myOptional: String?

logger.log ("MyOptional is \(myOptional)")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the (somewhat obfuscated) compiler error is that [`Logger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger) requires that the interpolated types conform to the [`CustomStringConvertible`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible) protocol, and that is *not* the case for `Optional`.

Depending on the desired output you can explicitly convert the optional to a string:

```
logger.log ("MyOptional is \(String(describing: myOptional))")
// Equivalently:
logger.log ("MyOptional is \(myOptional.debugDescription)")
```

which produces log lines like

```
MyOptional is nil
MyOptional is Optional("abc")
```

or use nil-coalescing to provide a default value:

```
logger.log ("MyOptional is \(myOptional ?? "<undefined>")")
```

which produces log lines like

```
MyOptional is <undefined>
MyOptional is abc
```

Answer (score 1):

I would handle it directly in the log call

```
var myOptional: String?
...
logger.log ("MyOptional is \(myOptional ?? "")")
```

or perhaps clearer

```
logger.log ("MyOptional is \(myOptional ?? "<nil>")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Optionally (:D), just write an extension for the `Optional` type for `CustomStringConvertible` conformance:

```
extension Optional: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return self.debugDescription
    }
}
```